# Proper way to set an attribute of nth element with XSLT

Tags: xml, qt, xslt

I have the following xml:

```
<t>
    <property>value1</property>
    <property type="oldtype">value2</property>
    <property type="oldtype">value3</property>
    <property type="oldtype">value4</property>
</t>
```

I want to set the type attribute of the second property element with XSLT.

Currently I have the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="pNewType" select="'newtype'"/>
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="property[2]/@type">
        <xsl:attribute name="type">
            <xsl:value-of select="$pNewType"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It works well with xsltproc and online xslt tools, but does not work with Qt's XSLT implementation. Is this the right way to do this transformation?

Qt's isValid() check function returns `true`, but the result of the transformation is the same as the input.

The expected output is:

```
<t>
    <property>value1</property>
    <property type="newtype">value2</property>
    <property type="oldtype">value3</property>
    <property type="oldtype">value4</property>
</t>
```

(without the "index"`[2]`, it works as expected, change all attributes)

Comment: The positional predicate `[2]` looks fine to me. What happens in QT, any specific error or any specific wrong result you can show?

Comment: Please don't tell us something doesn't work -- tell us how it fails!

Comment: Your code looks fine. Match patterns such as match="property[2]" are quite tricky to implement and it wouldn't surprise me to hear there's a processor that gets it wrong. Raise a bug report.

Comment: QT's isValid() check function returns true, but the result of the transformation is same as the input.  Unfortunately, there isn't any error message.

Comment: Tested the code with `xsltproc` and it works as desired. I support the suggestion of @MichaelKay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes that ought to work, and must be a bug in QT's XSLT implementation.

You might want to try something that's semantically equivalent but syntactically different to see if you can work around the bug.

The match expression is actually just a shorthand for:

```
property[position()=2]/@type
```

If that doesn't work you could try:

```
property[count(preceding-sibling::property)=1]/@type
```

Comment: property[count(preceding-sibling::property)=1]/@type is working with qt, but position is not